# Xcode 15 iPhone cancel content via network

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When Xcode15 & iOS17 finish run App with iPhone, Xcode will is very slow run at breakpoint.
I try to cancel content via network without wifi, it is userful, but not working well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUFlL.png)
the picture, it can't be operated to cancel by Xcode15 & iOS17.
so how can solve slow or close content via network on xcode15.

Does expert have a solution？